PyCharm знатно тормозит
Пользовался какое-то время VSCode, для того, чтобы писать код на пайтоне, поставил буквально неделю назад PyCharm и собираюсь им пользоваться достаточно долгое время. Однако за эту неделю, я заметил, что он довольно сильно тормозит, порой, даже не успевает за вводом кода, и при этом, будто бы совсем не использует ресурсы пекарни, по сравнению с VSCode. Подскажите, в чём проблема и как эту проблему можно решить?
Сборка:

I5-12400F
DDR4 3200 32 GB
RTX 4060 Ti 8 GB
SSD: 1 TB Adata SX8200PNP
HDD: 2 TB Seagate ST2000VX008

IDE стоит на HDD, в этом ли проблема? Поможет ли установка программы на SSD починить производительность?

Ну так попробуйте. Дело же 1 минуты - перенести нужные папки на ssd, кинуть обратно симлинки или junction ссылку и перезапустить пишарм

Во-первых PyCharm действительно очень тяжело ворочается. Он по жизни такой. Ну и да, все среды разработки нужно ставить на SSD. Тем более у вас целый 1Тб, чего экономить то. )

При таких характеристиках компа надо очень постараться для того, чтоб эти несчастные приложеньица начали тормозить. Интересно также посмотреть на печатанье кода в скрипте, которое опережает возможности реакции клавиатуры. Помнится, даже жидкий терминатор такого не мог. Это раз.

Попытки устроить свалку на компе путём монтажа разнородных по сути винчестеров скажутся на скорости неизбежно. Не будет ОС работать, особенно в случае с обменом данными на винчестерах, на полную мощность. Подумайте сами. Допустим, я копирую файлы с быстрого винта та медленный. Какова будет реальная скорость? Да. Не выше, чем скорость медленного винта. Это два.

На компе должно быть только то, что в работе. Свалку из фильмов и фото надо держать либо в облаке, либо на съёмном винте. Когда в системе только один быстрый винт, ОС работает быстро и эффективно. Питон тут и оболочки к нему ни при чём. Это три.
